# install mongodb on macOS

Tags: mongodb, terminal, directory, macos-catalina, cp

need help. i can't proceed with mongodb installation due to some issues with copying the directory from download to `/usr/local/bin`.

here's what do. tgz was extracted to my desktop

```
sudo cp /Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.2.7/bin* /usr/local/bin/
```

and here is the error i get

```
cp: /Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.2.7/bin is a directory (not copied).
```

i'm running on catalina 10.15.5 and terminal updated to .zsh

what could be the problem in this and what would be the solution?
i tried manually copying the binaries and they were copied but it ain't working even after following procedures from mongo installation documentation.

Comment: `sudo cp -r /Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.2.7/bin* /usr/local/bin/`
you have to use `-r` to recursively copy directories

Comment: thank you. didn't work either. i tried brew install mongodb-community@4.2 and it worked